# Derivative of ${{x + 3} \over x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can I check my workings with somebody for my calculations for the derivative of:

${{x + 3} \over x}$

and what ${dy\over dx}$ when x = -1

$\quad \,\, {{x + 3} \over x}$

$\Rightarrow {{x \over x} + {3\over x}}$

$\Rightarrow{1 + {3\over x}}$

$\Rightarrow{1 + 3{1\over x}}$

$\Rightarrow{1 + 3x^{-1}}$

$\Rightarrow f'(x) = {3\over x}$

at $x = -1$, ${dy\over dx} = -3$

Comment: Is the derivative of $x^{-1}$ equal to $x^{-1}$?

Comment: $y(x) = 1 + 3 x^{-1} \implies \dfrac{d}{dx} y(x) = \dfrac{-3}{x^2}.$

So, $$\dfrac{d}{dx} y(-1) = -3$$

Answer (score 2):

Derivative of $x^{-1}=-1x^{-2}=\frac{-1}{x^2}$. All other seems fine to me. You can also apply division rule $\frac{u}{v}'=\frac{(v.u'-u.v')}{v^2}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: write $$\frac{x+3}{x}=1+\frac{3}{x}$$ if $x\ne 0$ and that is $1+3x^{-1}$ and the first derivative is given by $$3(-1)x^{-2}$$